# Adding sdcard/usbdrive to android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, cyanogenmod

According to instructions in this [site](http://k3rnel.net/2011/01/10/try-cyanogenmod-7-on-the-android-emulator/). I added cyanogenmod ROM to my Android AVD. The AVD works fine, but it fails to detect/mount sdcard. 
Is there any way to get it working? 
Can I mount other devices/harddisk/usbdrives in my AVD ?

Thanks for your time.